# Android Studio Getting value from Textfield and inserting them into API url

Tags: flutter, api

The API im using is a car registry where you type in a numberplate and it will show details about the vehicle. Basically i have tried implementing a Textfield where i can retrieve it's value so i can insert in the API url (VALUE FROM TEXTFIELD). I have have tried implementing it using this tutorial: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/retrieve-input but with no luck.

```
Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response = await http
      .get(Uri.parse('https://v1.motorapi.dk/vehicles/(VALUE FROM TEXTFIELD)'),
       headers: {"X-AUTH-TOKEN": "rfrzsucnc7eo3m5hcmq6ljdzda1lz793",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",
      });

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    return Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}
```

I have tried to inserting Textfield in the widget but that didn't work

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late Future<Album> futureAlbum;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureAlbum = fetchAlbum();
    TextEditingController nummerpladeController = new TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Fetch Data Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child:
          FutureBuilder<Album>(
            future: futureAlbum,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Column( mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [ Text("Registreringsnummer: ""${snapshot.data!.registration_number}"),
                  Text("Status: ""${snapshot.data!.status}"),
                  Text("Type: ""${snapshot.data!.type}"),
                  Text("Brug: ""${snapshot.data!.use}"),
                  Text("Første registrerings dato: ""${snapshot.data!.first_registration}"),
                  Text("Vin nummer: ""${snapshot.data!.vin}"),
                  Text("Mærke: ""${snapshot.data!.make}"),
                  Text("Model: ""${snapshot.data!.model}"),
                  Text("Variant: ""${snapshot.data!.variant}"),
                  Text("Model type: ""${snapshot.data!.model_type}"),
                  Text("Farve: ""${snapshot.data!.color}"),
                  Text("Bil type: ""${snapshot.data!.chasis_type}"),
                  Text("Brændstof: ""${snapshot.data!.fuel_type}"),
                  Text("Sidste syn: ""${snapshot.data!.date}"),
                ], );

              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('${snapshot.error}');
              }

              // By default, show a loading spinner.
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the `TextEditingController` to a TextField widget like so:

```
TextField(
  controller: nummerpladeController,
);
```

To retrieve its value you have to call `nummerpladeController.text`

Furthermore, you currently are not able to access your nummerpladeController in your build method because it is defined in the initState method. To fix this, do the following:

```
late final TextEditingController nummerpladeController;
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureAlbum = fetchAlbum();
    nummerpladeController = new TextEditingController();
  }
```

You can read more about what `late` is here: https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#lazy-initialization

Comment: i have tried that and i got this error: Undefined name 'nummerpladeController'.

Comment: @mhmh Take a look at my updated answer